# Safe Deployment Addresses on Polygon

Tags: addresses, gnosis-safe

Does anyone know the Safe deployment addresses for Polygon mainnet (chain ID 137) for multiSendAddress, safeMasterCopyAddress, and safeProxyFactoryAddress?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, for Safe version 1.3.0 the addresses are

multiSendAddress: "0xA238CBeb142c10Ef7Ad8442C6D1f9E89e07e7761"

safeMasterCopyAddress: "0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E"

safeProxyFactoryAddress: "0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2",